# SQL Cast TinyInt with Case Statement

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a query that aggregates some commonly reported on data. Basically, I'm trying to determine when a resource has been used.

Unfortunately, my query is returning an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint.

```
insert into Utilization
select resource
       ,timesegment
       ,case when min(uc.casemain_id) is null then 0 else count(uc.casemain_id) end as InUse
from ...
group by resource, timesegment
```

The error is occurring on `InUse` and the targeted column is a tiny int. I have run the query independently, and the min and max values of the count are 0 and 4.

```
select min(InUse), max(InUse)
from (... the query above ...)
```

> returns: 0, 4

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

## Updates

Sample of combination that causes the error:

```
CREATE TABLE Usage(
    [Resource] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TimeSegment] [datetime] NULL,
    [InUse] [tinyint] NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TimeMap(
    [TimeSegment] [datetime] NULL,
    [Resource] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Case] [varchar](50) null,
    [Usage] [tinyint] NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BuildTimeUsageMap] AS
BEGIN
    truncate table Utilization;
    insert into Utilization
    select resource
           ,timesegment
           ,count(uc.casemain_id) as InUse
    from   timemap
    group by resource, timesegment
END;

exec BuildTimeUsageMap;
```

I have altered the select statement to be simplified (changed `count(*)` to `count(uc.casemain_id)` does return a count of non-null values, thank-you @ughai ). Also I have resolved the issue by changing the data type of InUse to a `smallint`.

While changing the datatype to `smallint` makes the problem go away, it does not explain why it doesn't work in the first place.

```
select min(InUse), max(InUse) from Utilization
```

> results: 0,4

Both of which should fit in a `tinyint`

Comment: Is there any `count(uc.casemain_id)`  > 255

Comment: `max(count(uc.casemain_id)) == 4` (Fixed my description to make that more clear)

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` for `Utilization`?

Comment: @ughai There is at least one record for every time instance in the source data, there may be 0 to many uses associated with it. The count returns a minumum of 1 if you don't watch for null cases

Comment: @kavius - What does this query return? `SELECT count(uc.casemain_id) end from (...) group by resource, timesegment`

Comment: You might be falling foul of one of SQL Server's [illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) (Where the result set shouldn't contain a problem value but due to some SQL Server optimizations, it attempts to convert more results than will actually appear)

Comment: @JasonW 22099 rows between the value 0, and 1 (I think)

Comment: Show us your WHERE condition. It is quite possible that there are bigger groups, which you filter out with WHERE - but SQL computes them in different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're falling foul of SQL Server's [illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) (where it performs certain actions in a different order to the [*logical* processing order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) for SQL statements and this raises errors that would not have been raised had it followed the logical order).

In such a circumstance, your only real option is to split the query into multiple queries. Note that subqueries/CTEs aren't enough to guarantee that the optimizer won't move things around sufficiently to cause these errors.

So I would:

a) Create a temp table with looser type constraints than the real table (i.e. uses `int` or `bigint` rather than `tinyint`) and populate it. This query should be the one that performs any aggregations and any filters.

b) (Optional) run a query looking, specifically for out-of-range values and raise specific error messages for any found

c) `INSERT` from the temp table into the real table.

Comment: "Illogical Errors" sounds logical at this point. I am going to need to take some time run some tests. Given my work around of changing the datatype to `smallint` worked, I would say this the best answer. I still don't like it.

Given this is a semi-temporary table already, I'll just change the datatype permanently in my case.

Comment: @Kavius - if you haven't, don't forget to vote on this issue on the connect site - the fact that we're still having to work around this issue (which is a violation of the SQL Standard) is, to say the least, irksome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CAST( case when min(uc.casemain_id) is null then 0 else count(uc.casemain_id) end AS TINYINT )
```

Comment: I stand corrected. The explicit cast *did* fix it. I swear I tried that.. 3 different times.

Comment: If issue sill exists then :
Could you run only select stmt and verify the results or create a temp table with [Usage] column as INT and then insert the results into it, 
I guess problem definitely with datatype.

Comment: I don't see how an explicit cast can stuff a value of 22,099 into a TINYINT in the destination table `Utilization`. Have you tried this fix with the insert part?

Comment: It's insert 22000 instances of 0 or 1, not the number 22000. Interestingly, it seems to be having a problem with the `min(uc.casemain_id)` this returns an `int` early in the processing which hangs around for some reason? If I remove the `case` altogether and only use the `count`, everything is fine (except I don't get the desired value).

Comment: Still, there is no *reason* why an explicit cast should fix this. I suspect that the above is just enough to force the server to pick a different plan and not raise an illogical error (link given in comment on question). Just about anything might change on the server again and cause the illogical error to return.

Comment: Actually, I have to rescind the answer. @Damien_The_Unbeliever correctly points out that it doesn't seem to work in all cases. The error continues to appear when the query is wrapped in a stored procedure. I will update the original post to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `InUse` is a TINYINT, you probably have more than 255 records in your query, so the overflow is the `COUNT(uc.casemain_id)` returning a value higher than 255. The MIN and MAX are not counting records - just highest and lowest values within your query. Replace your second query with COUNT(1) keeping the same group by to confirm the row count exceeding the TINYINT max size.

Comment: Based on the OPs comment, it seems he has checked the `min` and `max` values of the `count` and all counts are within the range of `tinyint`

Comment: Possibly, but not absolutely. I question if the group by was included.

Comment: I double checked my syntax. I did wrap the entire query (including the `group by`) in a select just to determine the what the bounds of the inserted value are going to be. They do resolve to 0 and 4.

Comment: @kavius - I am not questioning that your MIN and MAX resolve to 0 and 4. That makes sense. The issue is that your `CASE` is returning `COUNT` when not null. You responded to my inquiry on the question that the COUNT returns 22099 records, which is why you're getting the overflow trying to INSERT 22,099 into a TINYINT column, which can only support 255 as the max value.